# why one of my views works 4 times slower when I filter it with column1 = 'ABCD'

Tags: sql, oracle, view, plsql, toad

I have the following script. To reduce the execution time, I replaced get_function() with a constant 'ABCD' (   which is the result of get_function()  ). I expect to decrease the execution time ;while, interestingly the execution time is increased almost 4 times.

```
alter system flush buffer_cache; 
alter system flush shared_pool; 
Set timing on; 
declare x number(3); 
begin 
    select v.QTY 
    into x 
    from viewName v 
    where v.col1 = get_function() --'ABCD'; 
    exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm||' '||sqlcode); 
end; 
Set timing off;
```

Comment: It would help if you could show the definition of the view? Please show both the slow and fast views, and ideally show your schema as well. If you can create an example to demonstrate this on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) that would be perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far without the filter on column1, it might be using some indexes. Once you introduced column1 which is not part of any of these indexes, a table scan will be performed (since this is a varchar column) and hence the increase in the execution time. You should go through the execution plan of your view before and after the addition of this new filter on column1 and you will be able to figure out the right index definition/modification.

Comment: I just replaced the 'ABCD' with a function that calculate and return 'ABCD'. I expected an increase in my execution time, but the execution time decresed from 25 sec to 16 sec

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the execution plan changed between the two queries (the former being obviously more efficient).

Execution plans are computed independently for each query and two syntactically different queries have no reason to produce the exact same plan. Oracle use rules, statistics and generalization to produce a plan in a reasonable amount of time. Each step the CBO (Cost-Based-Optimizer) takes is an approximation that can lead to a sub-optimal plan. Usually, with up-to-date statistics, for simple queries, Oracle will produce a reasonable plan. Sometimes, you have to help Oracle choose the best plan with hints, hand-picked statistics, adjusted parameters or other optimizing tools.

Since you give no other indication, we can only speculate as to the reason why the second plan is worse. My first guess is that the second query produces an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` that is poorly suited whereas the first query produces an efficient `FULL TABLE SCAN`.

Comment: i just replace the get_function() with a constant 'ABCD'. function returns the 'ABCD' after some calculation. Do you still think that this is because of the index?

Comment: Why don't you run an explain plan and tell us? :)

Comment: Most likely you are getting different execution plans because the string 'ABCD' is a constant that will be treated differently from the result of a function that could vary (from the point of view of the optimizer). The constant could be checked against an histogram on the column whereas the function certainly won't. This could explain the difference in execution plan.

Comment: Also it's expected that the first execution will take more time if you flush the share pool (since all blocks will be fetched from disk). Try to run both queries first without timing, then measure the performance in another set of execution.

Comment: Hi Vincent, you were totally right. The reason is the indexes. I ran an explain plan and saw the huge differences. Thank you so much for your help :-)